# The output of the optimization(using GEKKO) is giving zero for the manipulated variable(IMODE=6)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I am trying to implement a level 2 self driving car using gekko optimization tool.
I am using *MODEL PREDICTIVE CONTROL* a control strategy to control the car .So in gekko ,I have chosen IMODE =6.

The delta_throttle and the delta_steering_angle are the manipulated variables(MV's).
These variables are the input to the car.

The gekko should solve and provide the value for those variables thus making the car move autonomously .

But unfortunately ,the software is just returning a zero value for both the variables.
I dont know why the software is providing zero.It should have provided a non zero values so that the car could have moved.

Can anyone help me out ?
THANKS!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three things to check:

1. The solver reports a successful solution. The solution status can be checked with:

```py
if m.options.APPSTATUS==1:
   print('Successful Solution)
else:
   print('Unsuccessful')
```

The solution status is also displayed when `disp=True` in `m.solve(disp=True)`.

2. The Manipulated Variable status is on.

```py
delta_throttle.STATUS = 1
delta_steering_angle.STATUS = 1
```

3. The Controlled Variable status is on such as for velocity and position.

```py
velocity.STATUS = 1
position.STATUS = 1
```

Here is a velocity MPC application for reference:

[image: MPC for velocity control]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,41)

# Parameters
mass = 500
b = m.Param(value=50)
K = m.Param(value=0.8)

# Manipulated variable
p = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100)
p.STATUS = 1  # allow optimizer to change
p.DCOST = 0.1 # smooth out gas pedal movement
p.DMAX = 20   # slow down change of gas pedal

# Controlled Variable
v = m.CV(value=0)
v.STATUS = 1  # add the SP to the objective
m.options.CV_TYPE = 2 # squared error
v.SP = 40     # set point
v.TR_INIT = 1 # set point trajectory
v.TAU = 5     # time constant of trajectory

# Process model
m.Equation(mass*v.dt() == -v*b + K*b*p)

m.options.IMODE = 6 # control
m.solve(disp=False)

# get additional solution information
import json
with open(m.path+'//results.json') as f:
    results = json.load(f)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,p.value,'b-',label='MV Optimized')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Input')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,results['v1.tr'],'k-',label='Reference Trajectory')
plt.plot(m.time,v.value,'r--',label='CV Response')
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sir,I have watched  your you-tube video for MPC for velocity of the car(example 17). Also I have written My code in similar way as yours . I have few doubts in the above code.Firstly how did you arrive at value of 5 for time constant,also for DMAX and DCOST                                                      Also It shows a success message for the problem and The step 2 is also followed properly   thanks!!!!

Comment: Please see the controller tuning information at https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerTuning  Please post your code as a new StackOverflow question if you need more specific help.